# How do I detect a change in my Text box JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Markup:

```
 <td width="300px"><strong>Last Name: </strong></td>
 <td width="300px"><input id="custL" type="text" name="txtLasttName" size="20" /></td>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$("#custL").on('input change keyup keydown keypress', function() {
    $("#custName").text($("#custL").val);
});
```

I have also tried .bind neither works

Here is where I want the changes reflected:

```
 <div>Welcome,
     <div id="#custName"></div>
 </div>
```

what is strange is when I key into the input box, I perform an Inspect element and the Value does not reflect the data that is typed in.

Comment: The value attribute doesn't change when you type, the property does, so you're not supposed to see any changes when inspecting the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a function

```
$("#custName").text($("#custL").val());
```

But since you are in an event handler binded to the same element try

```
$("#custName").text(this.value);
```

Also the div id attribute should not containt `#`.

```
<div id="custName"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N7QjA/)

Comment: Thanks it worked, I am not sure if I was missing something, but when I would inspect element I would not find the value

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

Replace your Jquery code with code below..

```
$("#custL").keyup(function() {
    $("#custName").text($("#custL").val());
});
```